# StackOverflow Old Database Schema

Tags: support, data-dump

I am pretty new to StackOverflow, but I have now heard of database dumps and that the database schema was changed recently (?) so that a lot of joins could be avoided. On the post I read this people were advising others to have a look at the old schema, but no links were provided. How can I, if it is that I can at all, check the old database schema?

Comment: Check the older database dumps.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/2678/revisions

Comment: Note that the data dump does not expose the exact schema used in production, so any discussion regarding denormalization may or may not apply to the data dump schema.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the old data dumps:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/

(scroll back to the beginning)