# Is database schema documentation available from the Stack Exchange Data Explorer? Shouldn't it be in the FAQ?

Tags: support, data-explorer

If you don't know where to look, [it's a bit hard to find the database schema for the Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70914/162705) ([both new *and* old](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97350/162705)). As far as I can tell, the Stack Exchange Data Explorer only provides one clue—in [the "About" page](https://data.stackexchange.com/about)—as to the whereabouts of the data schema.

> The Stack Exchange trilogy data dumps are hosted at
> [ClearBits](http://www.clearbits.net/torrents/1117-may-10)!. You can
> subscribe via
> [RSS](http://www.clearbits.net/feeds/creator/146-stack-overflow-data-dump.rss)
> and be notified every time a new dump is available. Have fun remixing
> and reusing; all we ask is for proper attribution.

However, I would argue that [this answer on Meta Stack Overflow provides the most accessible overview of the database schema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-data-explorer/2678#2678). Can someone add this to [the Data Explorer FAQ](https://data.stackexchange.com/faq) or show at least show me where it is prominently displayed on a Data Explorer page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As far as I can tell, the Stack Exchange Data Explorer only provides one clue—in the "About" page—as to the whereabouts of the data schema

Well, the schema is also shown under the Compose Query section *as long as you don't block scripts from microsoft.com.*

[image: schema-hidden]

[image: schema-shown]

Comment: D'oh! You're absolutely right. I had a script-blocker enabled, and that prevented the Microsoft-provided schema from being displayed.

Comment: @Chris :) thanks for updating my answer as well. Also, Microsoft provided schema? :-s

Comment: Er, what I *meant* to say was that the schema was shown by a script from microsoft.com and thus "Microsoft-provided".

Comment: @Chris ah okay!